# How to change the image contrast (window center and width) and display in QLabel(Python3.5, Qt5.1)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qimage, qlabel

I need to adjust the image contrast according to the window center and window width, then display in QLabel. Currently, the code is: ('self' in the following code is a subclass inherited from QLabel, the function 'qimage2ndarray.gray2qimage' is used to change a python variable (disImg) to a QT variable (QImg))

```
self.contrast['center']=-71
self.contrast['width']=800
disImg = (self.originalImg-self.contrast['center'])/self.contrast['width']+0.5
QImg = qimage2ndarray.gray2qimage(disImg)
self.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImg))
```

However, the image is just a black image.

I think that the problem may be fixed by normalized the intensity to 0~255, likes:

```
self.contrast['center']=-71
self.contrast['width']=800
disImg = (self.originalImg-self.contrast['center'])/self.contrast['width']+0.5
# normalization to 0~255
MIN = disImg.min()
MAX = disImg.max()
normImg = (disImg-MIN)/(MAX-MIN)
normImg = normImg*255
QImg = qimage2ndarray.gray2qimage(normImg)
self.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImg))
```

When I use the above code, the image can be correctly display. But the display image looks like the same after change the self.contrast['center'] and self.contrast['width']

Does someone meet the same problem? Please help me out, and thanks in advance. 
Qiang

Answer (score 0):

I has found the solution.

The QLabel focus on 0 ~ 255. For display image, we set the pixel which is smaller than 0 to 0, and the pixel which is lager than 255 to 255. Then, the QLabel correctly display the image, and the contrast is OK. The code is:

```
    MIN = (2*self.contrast['center'] - self.contrast['width'])/2.0 + 0.5
    MAX = (2*self.contrast['center'] + self.contrast['width'])/2.0 + 0.5
    dFactor = 255.0/(MAX-MIN)
    disImg = (self.originalImg - MIN)*dFactor
    disImg[disImg<0] = 0
    disImg[disImg>255] = 255
    QImg = qimage2ndarray.gray2qimage(disImg)
    self.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImg))
```